What is "i" in chrome memory heap snapshot?
I am doing a memory analysis for my application. And this i is taking a lot of space. It is storing many objects with same properties from application.



It's the name used by the minifier you're using for whatever it really is in your code. You'll need to look at the minified source or a source map, or inspect one of those objects to figure out what its actual name is.

@T.J.Crowder This is currently pointing towards a component that is destroyed. Should it exist in the memory? Do you know of any possible reason why it was not removed on ngOnDestroy?

I don't use Angular. But remember that just because an object is no longer used doesn't mean it's immediately removed from memory. That only happens later, when the garbage collector runs and identifies that the object is no longer reachable. So it may well be these are no longer in use but it hasn't been worthwhile yet to bother to reclaim their memory. You can use the "Collect Garbage" button on the Memory tab (it looks a bit like a floor brush) to trigger GC, although doing that won't necessarily reclaim all unreferenced objects, it's complicated.
